# ajaxtoolkit controls won't allow page to load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I installed ajaxtoolkit to my project and all worked fine.

Suddenly, when I added a new aspx web form and added some ajaxtoolkit controls to it, page won't load.
The following error occurs:

**"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure `AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources` was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."**

I guess it's something with the .NET framework...

**my web config file looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <!--connection string-->
    <connectionStrings>
          <add name="igroup20_test2ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Media.ruppin.ac.il;Initial Catalog=igroup20_test2;User ID=igroup20;Password=***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>

    <!--define membership-->
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomizedProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomizedProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="igroup20_test2ConnectionString" applicationName="ScottsProject" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <!--define roles-->
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="CustomizedRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="igroup20_test2ConnectionString" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>

    <!--define profile properites-->
    <profile defaultProvider="CustomProfileProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomProfileProvider"
             type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
             connectionStringName="igroup20_test2ConnectionString"
             applicationName="ScottsProject" />
      </providers>

      <!-- Define the properties for Profile... -->
      <properties>
        <add name="prof" type="String" serializeAs="String" />
      </properties>
    </profile>


        <authentication mode="Forms"/>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <!--<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>-->
            <assemblies>
                  <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                  <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                  <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>


    </system.web>

 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added the `ScriptManager` to your `Masterpage` - or standard Web forms if not using a `MasterPage`.

This needs to go inside your `<form runat="server">` tag

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```